# Oracle Apex Remove lines from Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to remove these white lines from the interactive report header with no success.
I have used CSS on the ''.t-Header a-MenuBar-Container'' and all the available ones but none seem to work.
Does anybody know how to remove them?

[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the CSS class `.a-IRR-header`, if you set property `box-shadow: none;` then it will remove the lines between the headers.

Before:
[image: Before - with lines]

After:
[image: After - without lines]